# Assignment with brackets

Tags: c++, initialization

On another SE site I saw code similar to this:

```
int x[] = {1,2,3,4};
....
x[0] = {99};
```

For the assignment, is there an advantage to this over simply:

```
x[0] = 99;
```

http://ideone.com/xwA0Yh

Comment: I think this might prevent implicit narrowing conversions, but for an int literal it's going to be absolutely irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is one.

Those brackets disable implicit narrowing conversions, so if the type of the expression inside does not fit an `int` it's an error instead of a silent loss of data.
Of course, `99` is plenty small and thus of type `int`.

Try it with a sufficiently large literal like `99999999999`: http://ideone.com/D89wVx